# Android Simple Map Application

Tags: android

Hi i have a developed a simple map application based on the tutorial from android developers site and have generated the API key and run in the google emulator still i'm not getting my map displayed in the emulator only grids are shown.........
 can anyone help me on this

thank you......

Comment: Are you sure your Internet is working? and you have added `Internet Permission` in your manifest? check if any URL is accessible via device/emulator browser.

Comment: plz paste your menifest file and code. have you used debug.keystore to generate key

Comment: Also look in the cat log if there are some errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure that you have Implement Following things.

1. Make Sure that you have selected  google Api
2. Add following permissions in manifest file

   ```
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" 
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"    

   uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
   ```
3. extend MapActivity  in your java class
4. API key but as you said you have already generated a key .

Try the above given.. and  hope now you will get the solution.